React Native TextInput maxLength not working after refocusing
I’m facing an issue with the maxLength property in React Native’s TextInput component.
The maxLength restriction works perfectly the first time I focus and type into the input. However, once I switch focus to another input or blur the current one, and then refocus on the original input, the maxLength no longer applies, allowing the user to type beyond the defined limit.
Here’s a summary of the issue:
When I first tap the TextInput to focus, the maxLength property works as expected.
After switching focus to another input (or simply blurring and refocusing), the maxLength no longer restricts the input.
Is this a known issue with React Native, or is there a workaround to ensure maxLength always applies, even after refocusing?
Any guidance or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

You can do this by adding an onFocus handler to the TextInput, ensuring that the property is enforced again when the input regains focus.


<TextInput
  value={yourValue}
  onChangeText={(text) => {
    if (text.length <= maxLength) {
      setYourValue(text);
    }
  }}
  onFocus={() => {
   // Reapply the maxLength here if needed
    setMaxLengthState(maxLength);
  }}
  maxLength={maxLengthState}
/>




Thank you for your suggestion! However, I’m encountering a different issue with the onFocus handler itself.
The problem is that the onFocus event fires correctly the first time I tap into the TextInput, and the maxLength works as expected. But after focusing on another input or blurring the original one, when I refocus on the same input, the onFocus handler doesn’t trigger again. This causes the maxLength to not reapply, and no logs from onFocus are being printed after the first focus.

I’ve confirmed that this isn’t just a logging issue; the maxLength actually stops working after refocusing. Do you have any suggestions on why onFocus might not be firing consistently after the first focus?

Ensure that each TextInput has a unique key prop, which can force the component to reinitialize when needed. If onFocus isn't firing the second time, try resetting relevant state or properties in the onBlur event, ensuring that the input is fully "reset" when it loses focus

Thank you for your suggestion! I tried adding a unique key prop and resetting state in the onBlur event as you recommended, but unfortunately, the issue still persists. The onFocus event is still only firing the first time, and after switching focus to another input and coming back, it doesn't trigger again.
I really appreciate your help though! If you have any other ideas or suggestions, I'd be happy to try them out.
